# How (or where) I can set keyboard shortcut to "add new desktop place"

Tags: macos, keyboard, desktop

please, how to set up **keyboard shortcut** to **"add new desktop place"**, that must be added via *"Mission Control"* and by mouse click to *"plus button"* (top right corner)?? I'm looking at *"system preferences"* -> *"keyboard"* -> *"Shortcut"* ... but there is no any settings for "add new desktop" or someone same.

Is there any way to set up this shortcut ??

**Many thanks for ideas.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a New Space in Mavericks using Applescript](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118700/create-a-new-space-in-mavericks-using-applescript)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script then make a shortcut to it in Automator.

In Mavericks, Applescript to create a new Space in Mission Control

```
delay 0.5 -- time to release command if the script is run with command-R
tell application "System Events"
    key code 126 using control down -- control-up
    delay 1
    do shell script "MouseTools -x 1900 -y 60;sleep 1;MouseTools -leftClickNoRelease;MouseTools -releaseMouse"
    key code 53 -- escape
end tell
```

<sub>source https://stackoverflow.com/a/22873544</sub>

Get the [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html)

Answer (score -1):

Move your mouse to the top right corner and you should see a dim plus sign and the new screen.

[image]